Section Navigation via GSAP animation goes only forward Nuxtjs
I have a nuxt3 app, with an index.vue page in the pages folder. I'm using layouts/default.vue instead of app.vue
I'm have this animation were it looks like the pages are sliding on top of each other on scroll/swipe. But I also have a Navbar with menu. If I use the menu I can go from home to about and from about to projects and so on. But if I want to go from projects to about, it stays on projects. And if I want to go from projects to home, I go to about?? I think it has something to do with the nextSection[index +1]
<template>
  <div>
    <section id="home"><Home /></section>
    <section id="about"><About /></section>
    <section id="projects"><Projects /></section>
    <section id="contact"><Contact /></section>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useNuxtApp } from '#app';

onMounted(() => {
  const { $gsap, $ScrollTrigger } = useNuxtApp();

  const sections = ['#home', '#about', '#projects', '#contact'];

  sections.forEach((section, index) => {
    const nextSection = sections[index + 1];

    $gsap.to(section, {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: section,
        start: 'top top',
        endTrigger: nextSection || 'bottom top',
        end: nextSection ? 'top top' : 'bottom top',
        pin: true,
        pinSpacing: false,
        scrub: true,
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<style scoped>
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>


I tried to add a previousSection = sections[index -1] in a if/else statement but it didn't work.
Expected behavior is of course that the nav works normally.
